# How to include observables in computed and get around resharper warning?

Tags: knockout.js, resharper

I'm trying to get around a resharper warning about unused variables.

Here is my current function:

```
self.contentDimensions = _i.ko.computed(function () {
    var fakeVarToFireComputed = self.contentSize() + self.ListLength();
    var firstEl = _i.$(itemSelector, self.viewRef()).first();
    if (firstEl.length > 0) {
        return { 
            width: firstEl.outerWidth(true), 
            height: firstEl.outerHeight(true) };
    } else {
        return self.contentDimensions();
    }
}, this, { deferEvaluation: true });
```

But since fakeVarToFireComputed isn't used, it throws a warning.

Here is what I've come up with:

```
self.contentDimensions = _i.ko.computed(function () {
    var fakeVarToFireComputed = self.contentSize() + self.ListLength();
    var firstEl = _i.$(itemSelector, self.viewRef()).first();
    if (firstEl.length > 0) {
        return { 
            width: firstEl.outerWidth(true), 
            height: firstEl.outerHeight(true),
            fake: fakeVarToFireComputed
        };
    } else {
        return self.contentDimensions();
    }
}, this, { deferEvaluation: true });
```

This gets rid of the warning, but is there a better way?

I tried searching for ways to include observables in a computed, but can't find a way unless you are actually using the value.  I am also not really seeing a way to rewrite this as some subscribes.

Comment: Can you provide more context as to why you need to reference `contentSize` and `ListLength` in the computed if they are not used by the computed? I see that `contentDimensions` can call itself. Does executing `contentSize` and `ListLength` on the first pass result in `firstEl.length` being greater than zero on the second pass? If so, why not just call `self.contentSize()` and `self.ListLength()` without storing them in an unnecessary local variable.

Comment: the `contentDimensions` computed is what is used to size a containing element an `<ol>` in my case.  this needs to be recalculated every time `contentSize` or `ListLength` changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need to call all observable to get them register in a computed... however, you don't need to actually use their values, just *execute* the observables.

In your case something like this will do the trick and prevent resharper warning

```
self.contentDimensions = _i.ko.computed(function () {
    self.contentSize(); //Something like this will be enough
    self.ListLength(); 
    var firstEl = _i.$(itemSelector, self.viewRef()).first();
    if (firstEl.length > 0) {
        return { 
            width: firstEl.outerWidth(true), 
            height: firstEl.outerHeight(true),
            fake: fakeVarToFireComputed
        };
    } else {
        return self.contentDimensions();
    }
}, this, { deferEvaluation: true });
```

In a working project I have dynamic dependencies, so I pre register them and my computed looks something like this

```
node.isValid = ko.pureComputed(function () {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.isValidDependencies().length; i++) {
                this.isValidDependencies()[i](); //Just call every dependency
            }
            //more code, validations bla bla bla
            },node);
```

Comment: thanks!  no idea why i didn't think of this.  resharper doesn't complain because it thinks you are executing a function, but KO picks up on the vars being there in the func string.